# Wordpress themes incomplete installation or installation problem

Tags: themes, localhost

when i install a theme it appears to be completely different and doenst shows contents which are supposed to be there. And nothing happens if a do changes from dashboard appearance and customize. kindly help!
[![see here][1]][1]

[![?][2]][2]

[image: ?]

[image]

Comment: Is there any dummy content xml came with these themes?

Comment: @RaviShinde where should i look for that xml file where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

From the two screens  you posted, the  installed  and the activated themes are different.

It seems you are showing **SKT Strong theme (activated)** and **Enlightenment theme(not activated)**.

Which one is supposed to show?

Comment: no actually i wanted to show that the theme design in left is different than theme preview the theme does not contains all that stuff and in the second image even if i install a theme and activate it, it dont have the desired design and contents

Answer (score 0):

> even if i install a theme and activate it, it dont have the desired design and contents

Do you mean that it doesn't have the "Worth a Thousand Words" and "Elements" content? If so, that is just part of the theme preview. It will never appear when you install the theme.